# getting this message A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond at the second request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I am using `HttpClient` to make a couple of requests instead of `httpwebrequest`. everything works fine specially when I make the first request.However when I make the second requests always falls and I end up with getting the A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. I did follow all the suggested answers from other posts but none of them has helped and also compared to `httpwebrequest` all the requests works fine even if I made more than one request.

```
private async Task <string> getSomeData(string jobUrl)
{
Uri myUri = new Uri(jobUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
//GET Method  
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(myUri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
String result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (result != null)
{
return result;
}
}
}
return "";
}
```

I did also set the deafult proxy to false:

```
 <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```